# Removing duplicated in a Collection based on condition

Tags: java, list, collections, foreach

I have a Collection of type `Person`

```
class Person {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
}
```

I would like to remove duplicates from this list, based on the condition -
if there are two elements in the list having the same firstname,
and lastname having a name in one and null in the other,
then the one having lastname is only retained in the list.

For Eg:
if there are 2 elements in the list, like

1. firstName = "John", lastName = "Doe"
2. firstName = "John", lastName = null

Only *John Doe* should be retained in the list.
There could be instances where in the `lastName` can be null provided it does not share the same `firstName` with another element in the list.

Also, I have a for each processing this information,

```
for(Person person : Persons) {
//I would like the duplication removal happening here
/*process(person)*/
}
```

How can I achieve this in the most optimal way. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What did you do so far?

Comment: are you looking for a rule? to filter the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(
    new Person("Tom","White"),
    new Person("Mark",null  ),
    new Person("Tom","Brown"),
    new Person("John","Doe" ),
    new Person("Tom","Black"),
    new Person("John",null  ),
    new Person("Tom",null));

    Map<String,Person> pmap = new TreeMap<String,Person>();

    for (Person p : persons) {
        Person other = pmap.get(p.firstName);
        if(other==null || other.lastName==null){
            pmap.put(p.firstName, p);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(pmap.values());
```

Output is

```
Person [firstName=John, lastName=Doe], Person [firstName=Mark, lastName=null], Person [firstName=Tom, lastName=White]]
```